# Optimizing connectivity queries in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

This is one of the personal projects that I am working on. I have a DAG of N nodes ( say million ) that I will querying for connectivity of two nodes [ isConnected(a,b} ]. I will be querying the DAG online M ( say million ) times. Is there a way to optimize the process?

Here are the best approaches that I could come up with.

BFS = O( M * N )

Dijkstra = O( M* E* log N) where E is the number of edges in the graph.

Is there any other better approach for this process ? I am right now using the second strategy. This takes forever in my system.

Comment: "querying" you mean searching ? What the action that you want to perform on this trees ?

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/#searching this should help

Comment: @user2485710 I will be checking if two nodes are connected. Using any of the pattern does not better my O(M * E* logN ) that I get from Dijkstra.

Comment: What does E means in O(M*E*logN) ?

Comment: Are the queries on-line or off-line. Off-line means that you known all queries before the search. On-line means the query comes one by one and you don't know them in advance.

Comment: @notbad I have edited the question. It is online querying. But if can be done efficiently offline, that would open me a door as well.

Answer (score 2):

I can see some speed-ups, but I cannot solve the problem efficiently in general.

First, consider the graph as an undirected graph and split it out into connected components. Two points not in the same connected component must be disconnected.

For each connected component, consider it again as a directed graph and split it into strongly connected components. Two points in the same strongly connected component must be connected.

Now consider each connected component as a DAG of nodes, where each node is actually a strongly connected component. You can topologically sort this. If node A is upstream from node B then there is no path against the flow from B to A.

Your DAG probably isn't a tree, but if it is you can solve the Lowest Common Ancestor problem problem on it efficiently. The only path from A to B goes up to its lowest common ancestor and back down again. If both those routes are in the right direction for a topological sort then you can get from A to B.

For a completely different approach, a google search will find many algorithms for fast shortest path in large networks. It is possible that some of these may be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The way to optimize the process is to generate some helper structure that would speed up reachability queries.  Even not taking into account the time to generate such structures (or update them), there is a matter of balance between the size of helper structure, and the speed of query.

This is quite well describe in the introduction to the [Reachability Queries in Very Large Graphs: A Fast Refined Online Search Approach](http://openproceedings.org/EDBT/2014/paper_166.pdf) paper; the approach proposed there is to use two additional numbers per vertex. You can find there references to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your graph it might be use full to look at some big data approaches. That is, if your graph is a few gigabytes big the memory/disk access becomes the bottleneck instead of the CPU operations.

Solving this type of issues requires that you somehow group your data such that you have to load data only once. Hence, you should make your data structure such that it can be divided in blocks that fit in memory and can be processed in one go and need no further processing later on.

One such big data approach for your problem is to divide the graph in connected subgraphs and only run Dijkstra on these subgraphs. Then after that you can simply check per subgraph whether the entry point and output point are actually connected (since you have a DAG) using Dijkstra again. This however, requires that you preprocess your data (once) and your data structure should be such that the subgraphs are memory blocks that are near to each other.

More details here:
[TRS: A New Structure for Shortest Path Query](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783642416286-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1428327-p176304553&ei=d4HXUsHoN4eK1AXG4YHgAg&usg=AFQjCNGvFT59lJLgaHiOivsr5mXjL323NQ&sig2=-FSSsle2ffUqL5KJQS773A&bvm=bv.59568121,d.d2k&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the DAG and then answer the queries in constant time. However, this requires up to O(n³) time and O(n²) memory. There are some methods that accept longer query times for faster preprocessing or lower memory use, see e.g. [this presentation](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~mengmeng/presentations/reachability.pdf).